# R Find the nearest convex curve "below" a set of points

Tags: r, polynomials

I have a set of points and I would like to find the convex curve that is the nearest "below" this set of points. 
As in the example below where every v,w points are above the qe curve.
Thanks for your help.

```
v<-c(-1,0,0,.5,1.2,1.7,-1,1.7);w<-c(3,0,2,4,3,3.4,1,2.89)
qe<-seq(min(v),max(v),length.out=10)**2
plot(v,w)
lines(seq(min(v),max(v),length.out=10),qe)
```

Comment: There are infinitely many such curves. Are you looking for a nearest one? If so, nearest in what sense?

Comment: @JuliusVainora You right, I mean the nearest one. It should be the nearest such as at least 3 points "touch" the curve. I edited my example

Comment: Also, do you need the curve to actually be quadratic, i.e., of the form y=ax^2+bx+c, or is it enough that it is convex?

Comment: @JuliusVainora Actually just a convex curve should be enough. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as the *Greatest Convex Minorant*. To find it we may use the `gcmlcm` function from the `fdrtool` package.

First, we need to make sure that there is only one unique value for each `x`. So, we replace `w` by

```
w2 <- tapply(w, v, min)
```

assigning the least value of `w` for each value of `v`. (In this case there were two values at `v = 0`.) And that's all, our result is

```
result <- gcmlcm(x = as.numeric(names(w2)), y = w2, "gcm")
```

which we may plot with

```
lines(result$x.knots, result$y.knots)
```

giving

[image]

And it works flawlessly in more complex cases as well:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Julius, I spent the 2 last hours to find a way to name this problem !

Comment: @MassCorr, glad to help! Indeed stating the problem often is key.